# Seaborn regplot fit line does not match calculated fit from stats.linregress or stats model

Tags: python, regression, seaborn, statsmodels

I am trying to fit a xlog-linear regression. I used Seaborn regplot to plot the fit, which looks like a good fit (green line). Then, because regplot does not provide the coefficients.  I used stats.linregress to find the coefficients.  However, that plotted line (purple) does not match the fit from Seaborn regplot.  I also used stats model to get the coefficients which matched the lineregress output. Is there a better way to get the coefficients that match the regplot line. I am unable to reproduce the Seaborn regplot line. I need the coefficients to report the fit for the model.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

sns.regplot(x, y,x_bins=100, logx=True,n_boot=2000, scatter_kws={"color": "black"},
        ci=None,label='logfit',line_kws={"color": "green"})

#Find the coefficients slope and intercept
slope, intercept, r_value, pv, se = stats.linregress(y, np.log10(x))

yy= np.linspace(-.01, 0.05, 400)
xx = 10**(slope*yy+intercept)
plt.plot(xx,yy,marker='.',color='purple')

#Label Figure
plt.tick_params(labelsize=18)
plt.xlabel('insitu', fontsize=22)
plt.ylabel('CI', fontsize=22)
```

[image: output from code shows lines do not overlay]

I also used stats model for the fit and got the same results as stats.linregress for the coefficients. I'm unable to reproduce Seaborn regplot line.

```
 import statsmodels as sm
 import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

 results = smf.ols('np.log10(x) ~ (y)', data=df_data).fit()
 # Inspect the results
 print(results.summary())
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your attempt to recreate what seaborn is doing:

- you have the arguments to `stats.linregress` backwards
- that's not how yhat is computed

Here's how you could recreate the seaborn logx regression line:

```
diamonds = sns.load_dataset("diamonds").sample(500, random_state=0)

x = diamonds["price"]
y = diamonds["carat"]

ax = sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, logx=True, line_kws=dict(color="g", lw=10))

fit = stats.linregress(np.log(x), y)
grid = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max())
ax.plot(grid, fit.intercept + fit.slope * np.log(grid), color="r", lw=5)
```

[image]